# Determining weakness of Instrumental Variables

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, instrumental-variables, exogeneity

The problem is about doing a regression on the impacts of `money` supply growth and `output` (GDP) growth on `inflat`ion rate growth:

$$
\mathrm{inflation} = \beta_1 + \beta_2\mathrm{money} + \beta_3\mathrm{output} + u
$$

The variable `output` is known to be **endogenous**. The variable `money` is **exogenous**.

There are four instrumental variables: `initial` level of GDP, `school` population education level measurement, `inv` average investment portion of GDP, `poprate` average population growth rate.

I used **r** to create a regression like so:

```r
# Full tsls regression
ivreg = ivreg(
    inflat ~ money + output | money + initial + school + inv + poprate,     
    data=brumm)

# First stage of two-stage-TSLS-regression
# Regressing endogenous X on the instrument variables and exogenous variables
reg = lm_robust(output ~ money + initial + inv + school + poprate,
                   data = brumm, se_type = "stata")
reg1 = lm_robust(output ~ money + initial, data = brumm, se_type = "stata")
reg2 = lm_robust(output ~ money + inv, data = brumm, se_type = "stata")
reg3 = lm_robust(output ~ money + school, data = brumm, se_type = "stata")
reg4 = lm_robust(output ~ money + poprate, data = brumm, se_type = "stata")

# Check for weakness
linearHypothesis(reg, 
                 c("inv=0", "school=0", "poprate=0", "initial=0"),
                 test=c("F"))
linearHypothesis(reg1, c("initial=0"), test=c("F"))
linearHypothesis(reg2, c("inv=0"), test=c("F"))
linearHypothesis(reg3, c("school=0"), test=c("F"))
linearHypothesis(reg4, c("poprate=0"), test=c("F"))
```

**The first linear hypothesis I do is all of the instrumental variables being 0, which results in F value < 10 which indicates at least one of them is weak. I wish to find out which variables are weak, so I do linear hypothesis for all of them individually. Is this the right way? the results show that all of the F values are < 10, so are all of the IVs weak?**